# ContextConfiguration annotation exception

Tags: java, spring

I have a pretty simple Spring Boot project that was just upgraded from `Spring Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE` to  `Spring Boot 1.3.0.M5` (which then relies on `Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE`), and now my project won't compile.

Project:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEncryptableProperties
public class MyApp extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Test that fails compilation (my only test ATM):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MyApp.class})
@DirtiesContext
public class MyDAO_DataTest {

    @Autowired
    MyDAO dao;

    @Test
    public void whenDoingAtest() throws Exception {
        //...
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, it fails on my test file, saying:

> org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException: In AnnotationAttributes for annotation [org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration] declared on [class com.example.MyDAO_DataTest], attribute [locations] and its alias [value] are declared with values of [{}] and [{class com.example.MyApp}], but only one declaration is permitted.

I found the [feature that's the origin of the exception](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11512), but I don't really understand what I can do about it.

**Update** I "fixed" the issue by changing this line:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MyApp.class})
```

... to this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyApp.class},
                      loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
```

effectively working around the issue and allowing myself to work, but I don't understand why I had to. `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` is described as **[Similar to the standard ContextConfiguration but uses Spring Boot's SpringApplicationContextLoader](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.x/api/org/springframework/boot/test/SpringApplicationConfiguration.html)**, so what's the deal?

Comment: Just a friendly note that if you find one of the answers to your question acceptable, feel free to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Spring Boot 1.3.0.M5 (which then relies on Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE)

That is unfortunately incorrect: Spring Boot 1.3.0.M5 depends explicitly on Spring Framework 4.2.1, not 4.2.0.

The exception you are seeing was addressed in Spring Framework 4.2.1, specifically in the following issues.

- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13325
- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13345

And changes made to `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` in Spring Boot 1.3.0 M5 **require** Spring Framework 4.2.1. See the following issue for details.

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3635

Thus, ensuring that you are running against Spring Framework 4.2.1 should resolve your problem.

Regards,

Sam